# Mustache.js escaping "/"

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I have a simple JSON file as shown below:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "United Colors of Benetton Men's Shirt",
            "description": "Cool, breezy and charming – this solid green shirt from United Colors of Benetton is born on the beach. Effortlessly classy, this full sleeved shirt is perfect when worn with faded blue jeans and a pair of shades for a weekend get-together.",
            "quantity": "10",
            "cost": "3.00",
            "brand": "United",
            "image": "catalog/images/img2.jpg",
            "category": "1",
            "popularity": "100"
        }

    ]
}
```

I am displaying this JSON file using Mustache.js into the template blow:

```
<table class="product-list">
    {{#products}}
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <table class="product">
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-image">
                        <img src"{{image}}" height="150" width="150" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-details">
                        <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
                        <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
                        <p class="quantity"><b>Quanity Available: </b>{{quantity}}</p>
                        <p class="cost"><b>Cost: </b>&pound; {{cost}}</p>
                        <p class="brand"><b>Brand:</b> {{brand}}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/products}}
</table>
```

Everything works fine but for some reason the slashes in the image property are escaped due to which the images don't show up.

I've tried escaping slashes in the JSON file by adding a backslash in front of them. But instead of correct path I get this.

```
catalog\&#x2f;images\&#x2f;img2.jpg
```

I also try disabling HTML escaping by using {{{ image }}} and I get this.

```
catalog\="" images\="" img2.jpg=\""
```

How can I display the image property properly?

Can anyone please help me with this?

**Edit:** JS used to generate the template:

```
$template = $('#product-template').html();
$renderedHtml = Mustache.render($template, $data);
$('#content').html($renderedHtml);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From what I see it should work with triple mustaches `{{{image}}}`. You are also missing `=` after `src`.

Example fiddle:

```js
var jsn = {
  "products": [{
      "title": "United Colors of Benetton Men's Shirt",
      "description": "Cool, breezy and charming – this solid green shirt from United Colors of Benetton is born on the beach. Effortlessly classy, this full sleeved shirt is perfect when worn with faded blue jeans and a pair of shades for a weekend get-together.",
      "quantity": "10",
      "cost": "3.00",
      "brand": "United",
      "image": "http://static.cilory.com/26111-large_default/united-colors-of-benetton-men-white-t-shirt.jpg",
      "category": "1",
      "popularity": "100"
    }

  ]
};

var t = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
var m = Mustache.to_html(t, jsn);
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = m;
console.log(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/template">
  <table class="product-list">
    {{#products}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="product">
          <tr>
            <td class="product-image">
              <img src="{{{image}}}" height="180" width="150" />
            </td>
            <td class="product-details">
              <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
              <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
              <p class="quantity"><b>Quanity Available: </b>{{quantity}}</p>
              <p class="cost"><b>Cost: </b>&pound; {{cost}}</p>
              <p class="brand"><b>Brand:</b> {{brand}}</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/products}}
  </table>
</script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: I've added the JS code. I can see in your example the path comes up correctly but images aren't sill loaded. Even if I put them in root directory and call them using "image1.jpeg" they aren't still displayed.

Comment: @JayBhatt: Ah, crap, I missed `=` after `src`, which it also looks like you did ;) Updated sample fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

override the mustache.js `escape` function to not escape texts:

```
    mustache.escape = function (text) {
      return text;
    };
```