# unable to set the img src on the template using mustache js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am trying to set the img src value as shown below using mustache js. But not able to render that from the template.Not even able to see the src tag on the img

`<img class="photo" width="200" src="{{ logoImage }}" />`

where logoImage has the img src. But when the template is generated, I don't even see the src attribute on the img tag.

Comment: Try `src="{{{logoImage}}}"` this should escape the image path which  might be the problem. If it doesn't work please include the code that it's generating now to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mustache.js escaping "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820162/mustache-js-escaping)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out that issue.Actually I am sending dataURI as img src and mustache doesn't seem to have any problem. The email client is rejecting the dataURI in the template sent.

Answer (score 1):

If in condition like `logoImage` having path including slashes(`/` or `\`), so in that case use `{{{logoImage}}}` otherwise `{{logoImage}}` will work like a charm.